# What does the notation $\lim_{m,n\rightarrow\infty}||f_m-f_n||_D=0$ mean and how can I prove Cauchy's criterion for uniform convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis

$(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions which map from $D$ to $\mathbb{C}$

I want to show that

$$\lim_{m,n\rightarrow\infty}||f_m-f_n||_D=0\iff||f_n-f||_D\rightarrow0$$

By Definition a sequence of functions converge uniformly if there is a function $f$ such that $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\epsilon,\forall n\geq n(\epsilon),\forall_{z\in D}$. Which is the right side of the above equivalence in a more detailed form. The difference between pointwise convergence is that $n(\epsilon)$ is Independent from the chosen  $z\in D$.

I start with $||f_n-f||_D\rightarrow0\Rightarrow \lim_{m,n\rightarrow\infty}||f_m-f_n||_D$

Like I have said I don't know what the notation means. But since I want to prove the Cauchy-Criterion it is I think (correct me if I am wrong) equivalent to

$$\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{n_0\in\mathbb{N}}\forall_{m,n>n_0}\forall_{z\in D}|f_m(z)-f_n(z)|<\epsilon$$

$$(1)|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2},\forall n\geq n(\frac{\epsilon}{2})0:n_0,\forall_{z\in D}$$

Suppose $m,n>n_o$ and a $z_0\in D$ such that $|f_m(z_0)-f_n(z_0)|\geq \epsilon$ then

$$|f_m(z_0)-f_n(z_0)|=|f_m(z_0)-f(z_0)+f(z_0)-f_n(z_0)|$$

$$\leq |f_m(z_0)-f(z_0)|+|f(z_0)-f_n(z_0)|< \epsilon$$

Contradiction!

Can somebody give me a hint how I can show the other implication please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $\|f\|_D$ stands for $\sup \{|f(z)|: z\in D\}$. Suppose $\|f_n-f_m\|_D \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$. Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $n_0$ such that $|f_n(z)-f_m(z)|<\epsilon$ for all $z \in D$ for all $n,m \geq n_0$. I particular, if you fix $z$ in $D$ you see that $\{f_n(z)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence of complex numbers. Hence it has  a limit. Call this limit $f(z)$. Take limit as $m \to \infty$ in above inequality. You get $|f_n(z)-f(z)|\leq \epsilon$  for all $n \geq n_0$. This is true for all $z \in D$. Hence $\|f_n-f\|_D \leq \epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$. This finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the answer is to recognize that for a fixed $Z\in D$, $(f_n(z))$ is a  sequence in $\mathbb{C}$. And because

$$\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{n_0\in\mathbb{N}}\forall_{m,n>n_0}\forall_{z\in D}|f_m(z)-f_n(z)|<\epsilon
$$

holds. It is also Cauchy which is equivalent to convergence therefor we can define a function $f$ with $$f(z):=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(z)$$

The equivalence of Cauchy and Corvergence requires to understand the Theorem of bolzano Weierstrass which again requires to understand the Concept of nested intervals.